# ServiceStack adopting SemVer

Tags: servicestack

Are there any plans for the ServiceStack packages to start using the [SemVer](https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning#really-brief-introduction-to-semver) standard? We just had an unfortunate circumstance where we were broken by the interface breaking changes introduced in 4.0.44 from 4.0.43 around OrmLite.

We are a sizable commercial customer and have a custom implementation of a OrmLiteDialectProvider for one of our DBMSs, it all seemed good upon the initial upgrade in our web application, however as part of testing the changes around type converting broke our system. This wasn't initially evident as part of the upgrade because our custom implementation is in a NuGet package which overrides OrmLiteDialectProvider.ConvertDbValue on version 4.0.38 which is now gone. There were no binding issues because it is only a minor version difference.

[NuGet adopted SemVer back in version 1.6](http://blog.nuget.org/20140924/supporting-semver-2.0.0.html).

Having the SemVer standard would make it a lot easier for us to know when interface breaking changes have been made, without having to dig through the Release Notes page.

NOTE: The release also didn't indicate that the old method had been removed and upgrading would break any custom implementations.

**UPDATE FROM RESPONSE**

Anyway, fair enough answer. I can appreciate it would be difficult to track each package individually. In our case we wrote a custom dialect provider as we have a legacy DBMS that wasn't supported and this appeared to be the way we were supposed to add the support. We wanted to use ORMLite because we use the rest of ServiceStack and it's a fantastic product.
The new way to support the types is a great improvement and actually made our implementation easier.

We actually ran into this issue because we do always keep our ServiceStack packages inline and were upgrading the ASP portion for some fixes to the WSDL generation and this came along as part of our upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack adopts a single rolling version for all NuGet packages which all share the same Version number. Of all ServiceStack's 60 NuGet packages it's likely there's a breaking change to at least one of the packages so semver would be useless, you should also never mix and match different versions of ServiceStack together - when you upgrade, upgrade all packages to reference the same package versions. We do aim to keep user-facing breaking changes to a minimum, by looking to deprecate old API's first, maintain parallel API versions for a while then list the new API's release notes.

#### IOrmLiteDialectProvider is not a user-facing interface

However `IOrmLiteDialectProvider` is not considered a user-facing interface since it should be extremely rare that anyone implements their own custom provider. It's also the interface for specialization for all RDBMS's and often changes with every release to support new features, internal refactoring, optimizations, etc. E.g. implementing [Type Converters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/wiki/OrmLite-Type-Converters) was a major internal refactor that required changes to `IOrmLiteDialectProvider` but did not affect OrmLite's external user-facing API, later releases includes optimizations requiring further changes, again this doesn't affect OrmLite's external user-facing API.

SemVer won't help here, every ServiceStack version potentially has a breaking change in some of the packages and we have no intention to complicate each release by versioning each of the individual packages differently. The issue you're having is depending on an unstable Interface that's not intended for customization. It's not treated as a user-facing API so we don't try to maintain compatibility with existing versions or publish breaking changes which happens nearly every time we add features / optimizations to OrmLite. You should instead check the [commit history of 
IOrmLiteDialectProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commits/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/IOrmLiteDialectProvider.cs) for any changes to this interface.